# Evolution Equation

Tags: semigroup-of-operators

Let $X=L^2(0,\pi)$. Define the operator $(A,D(A)$ by: $$D(A)=\{u\in H^2(0,\pi):u(0)=u'(\pi)=0\} ,\quad \quad Au=u''$$ Show that $A$ is the infinitesimal generator of a $C_0$ semigroup of contractions on $X$.

Comment: The comment and the link is very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> **Theorem (Lumer-Phillips).** Let $X$ be an Hilbert space and $A : D(A)\subset X  \to X$ a densely defined dissipative linear operator. If there exists $\lambda > 0$ such that $(\lambda I -A):D(A)\to X$ is surjective, then $A$ is the infinitesimal generator of a $C_0$ semigroup of contractions on $X$.
>
> *Reference:* [Pazy's book](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=GAA2XqOIIGoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=brezis%20functional%20analysis&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=MkjuU_uJDIresAT4toGoBA&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=brezis%20functional%20analysis&f=false), page 14.

Notice that $X=L^2(0,\pi)$ is an Hilbert space, $D(A)$ is dense in $X$ (because $H_0^1(0,\pi)\subset D(A)$) and $A$ is linear. Furthermore, from integration by parts it follows that
$$\langle Au,u\rangle_{L^2}=-\|u'(x)\|_{L^2}^2\leq 0$$
and thus $A$ is dissipative. Finally, from the Lax-Milgram Lemma (see [Brezis book](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=GAA2XqOIIGoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=brezis%20functional%20analysis&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=MkjuU_uJDIresAT4toGoBA&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=brezis%20functional%20analysis&f=false), pages 220-221) it follows that, for each $f\in X$, the equation $u-u''=f$ has an unique solution $$u\in H^2(0,\pi)\cap H_0^1(0,\pi)=D(A)$$ and thus $\lambda I-A$ is surjective for $\lambda =1$.

So, from Lumer-Philips Theorem we get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Adapt the proof from http://www.math.unipr.it/~lunardi/LectureNotes/I-Sem2005.pdf page 25.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Adapt your answer...